# How to write the query to count the number of specific records in another table without foreign key?

Tags: mysql, yii, yii-cactiverecord

Below is the er diagram of my Db 
[image: ER-diagram]
I want to get all the results from table Subscription for given Subscription.ClientId with number of Assigned.ScreenId for each Subscription.RouteId for that Subscription.ClientId.
I have tried the code below, I also tried adjusting relations but with no success, How can I do it in yii.

```
SELECT S. * , (

SELECT COUNT( C.ScreenId ) 
FROM (

SELECT B.ScreenId, A.RouteId, B.clientId
FROM Screens AS A
INNER JOIN Assigned AS B ON A.ScreenId = B.ScreenId
) AS C
WHERE S.RouteId = C.RouteId
) AS couNTER
FROM Subscription AS S
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Here is the link to sample http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/38f2e7 [note:I removed table subscribedscreens]

What i want as output is

```
RouteId ClientId NumScreen NumAds... (Count(assignedScreenid)for given route)
1        1                              2
2        1                              1
1        2                              1
2        2                              3
```

Comment: consider providing some sample data in http://sqlfiddle.com along with the expected result set to your question from the given sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Have a go with the below sql, and if the result is not what you're after then maybe clarify the results you were expecting.

```
-- SELECT subscription.SubscriptionId, client.clientId, assigned.ScreenId, route.RouteId
SELECT route.RouteId, client.clientId, COUNT(assigned.ScreenId)
FROM subscription
  LEFT JOIN client ON client.ClientId = subscription.ClientId
  LEFT JOIN assigned ON assigned.ClientId = client.ClientId
  LEFT JOIN route ON route.RouteId = subscription.RouteId
GROUP BY assigned.ScreenId
```

Results:

```
ROUTEID   CLIENTID   COUNT(ASSIGNED.SCREENID)
   2         1         4
   2         1         2
   2         1         6
   1         2         2
```